# Is the word [that] here correct in part of the whole sentence "those of 【that】 were not organic were found to be 52%“

Tags: expressions

The original sentence in an essay example is "According to a study conducted on corns and berries grown organically, the antioxidant levels were found to be at 58%, while **those of [that]** were not organic were found to be 52%."
My questions is whether the word [that] here is correct? I sort of incline to use the word "what".

Answer (score 3):

No, it's wrong.

The writer uses the pronoun those to refer to "antioxidant levels** and means by **that** to refer to non-organic corns and berries.

**That** is singular and **corns and berries** is plural. But to correct this by writing ....**while those** (levels) **of those** (corns and berries) **that were not.....** is merely confusing.

The options are to write either: **....while levels in those that were not grown organically.....**

Or to rephrase slightly:

**...while those not grown organically showed levels of....**